# Set a start date and a end date to a kubernetes cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

I would like to create a kubernetes Cronjob that create jobs (according to its schedule) only if the current date is between a configurable start date and end date.

I can't find a way to do this with the basic cronjob resource. Is there a way to do this ? Ideally without resorting to overkill components (airflow ...) ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no way to configure the end date. You can run it in every day. You have to stop it manually when the end date will come.